# 502 Bad gateway on big file uploads : Nginx + PHP-FPM

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx, php-fpm, php.ini

I'm running php-fpm on nginx

I have my php.ini values set as follows

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 128M
max_execution_time = 180
```

I have also set my client_max_body_size to 4G. When I try small uploads they work, but when I try a big upload of say 35M I get a 502 and when I look through the logs I see ,

```
upstream sent unexpected FastCGI record: 3 while reading response header from upstream
```

Any ideas? I've tried the nginx threads but they don't really help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to check the PHP error logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I checked my logs and though I have all ini parameters related to logs turned on, I don't see any errors in my php-fpm.log file. Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: that's probably not where errors are logged. Check your `php.ini` to see if you even have logging enabled.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, `log_errors = On` and `error_log = /var/log/php.log`

EDIT: php-fpm logs are also turned on and I find this on that " `WARNING: [pool www] child 920 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39277825 bytes) in Unknown on line 0"
`

No error logs in php.log

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I was trying a file of size 35M and so I'd set the memory_limit to 64M. Looks like irrespective of what the actual uplaod is, the memory_limit needs to be higher than max_upload_filesize. TIL. Thanks!

Comment: I've made a full answer out of it so that you can accept it, which marks the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step: ensure you have error logging enabled in `php.ini` and check the log entries.

From your log entry:

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 920 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39277825 bytes) in Unknown on line 0"
```

It appears PHP has run out of memory processing the uploaded file. You will need to increase the `memory_limit` parameter. [Further information on upload tuning can be found at the PHP web site](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php).